# Magento2 di:compile error

Tags: error, magento2, dependency-injection, code-generation

After successfully installed Magento2-stable version, when I try to run `php bin/magento di:compile`, It gives me below error

```
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 1 hr 566.0 MiBErrors during compilation:

        WrongArgumentsOrder
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \stdClass. Actual type: \ClassExtendsDefaultPhpType; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Reader/_files/ClassesForArgumentsReader.php

        ArgumentsOnSeparateLines
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \stdClass. Actual type: \ClassExtendsDefaultPhpType; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Reader/_files/ClassesForArgumentsReader.php

        ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedIntoContext
                Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedIntoContext in E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

\ClassA already exists in context object

        ClassArgumentWrongOrderForParentArguments
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Context. Actual type: \ClassA; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

        ClassArgumentWithWrongParentArgumentsType
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: array. Actual type: \ClassB; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

        ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedInContext
                Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedInContext in E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForContextAggregation.php

\ClassFirst already exists in context object

        ClassArgumentWithAlreadyInjectedInterface
                Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentWithAlreadyInjectedInterface in E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForContextAggregaton.php

\InterfaceFirst already exists in context object

        Magento\SomeModule\Model\Five\Test
                Missed required argument factory in parent::__construct call. File: E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Five/Test.php

        Magento\SomeModule\Model\Four\Test
                Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $factory. File: E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Four/Test.php

        Magento\SomeModule\Model\Six\Test
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\SomeModule\Model\Proxy. Actual type: \Magento\SomeModule\Model\ElementFactory; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Six/Test.php

Total Errors Count: 10

Errors during compilation:
        WrongArgumentsOrder
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \stdClass. Actual type: \ClassExtendsDefaultPhpType; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Reader/_files/ClassesForArgumentsReader.php

        ArgumentsOnSeparateLines
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \stdClass. Actual type: \ClassExtendsDefaultPhpType; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Reader/_files/ClassesForArgumentsReader.php

        ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedIntoContext
                Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedIntoContext in E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

\ClassA already exists in context object

        ClassArgumentWrongOrderForParentArguments
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Context. Actual type: \ClassA; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

        ClassArgumentWithWrongParentArgumentsType
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: array. Actual type: \ClassB; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

        ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedInContext
                Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedInContext in E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForContextAggregation.php

\ClassFirst already exists in context object

        ClassArgumentWithAlreadyInjectedInterface
                Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentWithAlreadyInjectedInterface in E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForContextAggregation.php

\InterfaceFirst already exists in context object

        Magento\SomeModule\Model\Five\Test
                Missed required argument factory in parent::__construct call. File: E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Five/Test.php

        Magento\SomeModule\Model\Four\Test
                Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $factory. File: E:/wamp/www/magento2stable/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Four/Test.php

        Magento\SomeModule\Model\Six\Test
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\SomeModule\Model\Proxy. Actual type: \Magento\SomeModule\Model\ElementFactory; File: vendor/magento/framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Six/Test.php

Total Errors Count: 10
```

Can any one have faced the same error while `di:compile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, I have already reported it on GutHub a week ago: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2365

Comment: In stable version still it show the error? And Have you solved this error ?

Comment: My Magento 2 works in the Developer mode and does the compilation automatically on demand (on the first page load), so I just do no use di:compile yet.

Comment: If I don't  run this commnad and when I try to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade, then it gives me error like ,, Please re-run Magento compile command

Comment: So I am not able install my M2 extension ,, You have any solution for that ? @Mage2.PRO

Comment: Just ignore the message "Please re-run Magento compile command".

Comment: Without that how can I install my extension ? I mean without php bin/magento setup:upgrade command

Comment: Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` but ignore the "Please re-run Magento compile command" message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31852/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-mage2-pro).