# Warnings and errors during setup:di:compile-multi-tenant

Tags: magento2, error, code-generation

running latest `develop` branch on Windows 8.1 PHP 7.0rc5:

```
$ $PHP -d memory_limit=1024M -f bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
PHP Warning:  Declaration of Magento\Newsletter\Test\Unit\Model\Queue\TransportBuilderTest::testGetTransport($templateType = Magento\Framework\App\TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_HTML, $messageType = Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface::TYPE_HTML, $bodyText = '<h1>Html m...') should be compatible with Magento\Framework\Mail\Test\Unit\Template\TransportBuilderTest::testGetTransport($templateType, $messageType, $bodyText, $templateNamespace) in C:\dev\www\magento2\app\code\Magento\Newsletter\Test\Unit\Model\Queue\TransportBuilderTest.php on line 11
...
Errors during compilation:
    Magento\Framework\Code\Test\Unit\Generator\TestAsset\TestGenerationClass

            Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist
    WrongArgumentsOrder
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \stdClass. Actual type: \ClassExtendsDefaultPhpType; File: C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/Reader/_files/ClassesForArgumentsReader.php

    ArgumentsOnSeparateLines
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \stdClass. Actual type: \ClassExtendsDefaultPhpType; File: C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/Reader/_files/ClassesForArgumentsReader.php

    ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedIntoContext
            Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedIntoContext in C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php \ClassA already exists in context object

    ClassArgumentWrongOrderForParentArguments
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Context. Actual type: \ClassA; File: C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

    ClassArgumentWithWrongParentArgumentsType
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: array. Actual type: \ClassB; File: C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForConstructorIntegrity.php

    ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedInContext
            Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentAlreadyInjectedInContext in C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForContextAggregation.php \ClassFirst already exists in context object

    ClassArgumentWithAlreadyInjectedInterface
            Incorrect dependency in class ClassArgumentWithAlreadyInjectedInterface in C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/Validator/_files/ClassesForContextAggregation.php \InterfaceFirst already exists in context object

    Magento\SomeModule\Model\Five\Test
            Missed required argument factory in parent::__construct call. File: C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Five/Test.php

    Magento\SomeModule\Model\Four\Test
            Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $factory. File: C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Four/Test.php

    Magento\SomeModule\Model\Six\Test
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\SomeModule\Model\Proxy. Actual type: \Magento\SomeModule\Model\ElementFactory; File:C:/dev/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/Test/Unit/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/Model/Six/Test.php

Total Errors Count: 11
```

On the web getting:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reported about it 13 days ago: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2365
It also has been reported here in magento.stackexchange.com 7 days ago: [Magento2 di:compile error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90858)